# Fix QR Code dimensions (height and width) in ZPL

Tags: qr-code, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am printing a QR code on a small label.

The amount of data in the QR code is variable. The printer (e.g. Zebra GK420d) changes the size/dimensions of the QR image based on the amount of data being embedded.

Example ZPL:

```
 ^FO38,2400
 ^BQN,2,10
 ^FDMA,http://ghospitals/gp/index.php/patient/120704^FS
```

The QR code size should be fixed. An increase in data should increase the density not the size!

How can I restrict/define the dimensions of the printed QR code?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was experimenting with that for some time. I don't think that is possible to fix dimension when you are using `zpl II` script instead generate image from QR an scale it to that dimension.

If you won't use QR as image try to manipulate with magnification factor. From [doc](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) :

```
^BQa,b,c,d,e

c = magnification factor

Accepted Values: 1 to 10
Default Value: 
1 on 150 dpi printers
2 on 200 dpi printers
3 on 300 dpi printers
6 on 600 dpi printers
```

So In your case insted :

```
^BQN,2,10
```

use

```
^BQN,2,9
```

or less.

Comment: I guess it is safest to use an image.

Comment: The doc link is no longer valid.